# MVC controller differences between this.Response and this.HttpContext.Response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

MVC controller has many object which exists in HttpContext subobject too. What are differences between this objects?

```
        var res = HttpContext.Response;
        var res1 = Response;

        var req = HttpContext.Request;
        var req1 = Request;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Request` and  `Response` properties of the `Controller` class are really just returning `HttpContext.Request` and `HttpContext.Response`. There is no difference in the two. The presence of the `Controller` properties is really for succinctness to avoid using `HttpContext.Request` / `HttpContext.Result`.

You can see it in the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Controller.cs):

```
public abstract class Controller 
{
    // ...

    public HttpRequestBase Request
    {
        get { return HttpContext == null ? null : HttpContext.Request; }
    }

    public HttpResponseBase Response
    {
        get { return HttpContext == null ? null : HttpContext.Response; }
    }

    // ...

}
```

You should, however, use the `Controller` properties as they are directly related to MVC and not the System.Web.dll stack. If, in the future, there is a change in the MVC framework in regards to the Request / Response object model in such a way that the dependency with the System.Web and `HttpContext` class is removed, the `Request` and `Response` of the `Controller` itself should reflect directly what is is, and will require less change in code of your part (even though I think it's unlikely we see this kind of breaking change in the near future).